# autocorrelation of multiple signals

Tags: autocorrelation, correlation, adaptive-filters, multi-channel

**Problem:** I am looking at an adaptive filtering application where the eigenvaluespread of the autocorrelation matrix $R$ is important for the convergence of the algorithm. For a **single** channel system the autocorrelation matrix $R$ for iterationstep $n$ can be calculated by $R=E\{ x(n)  x^H(n)\}$ where $x(n)$ is the input signal of the adaptive filter at iterationstep $n$ consisting of a number of samples $N$ recorded over a timespan. The calculation of the eigenvalues is straight forward.

**Question:** What is the "multichannel equivalent" for $R$ in the case of e.g. an adaptive filtering **multichannel** application? Do I need to calculate some sort of autocorrelation tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the same formula, but instead of using a scalar $x(n)$, you will have $x(n) \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times 1}$, where $M$ is the number of channels, and $x^{H}(n)$ is the $1 \times M$ matrix whose entries are the complex conjugate of the entries in $x(n)$. As a result $R \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times M}$ is an [Hermitian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), and its eigenvalues are all real.

Comment: But wouldnt $R \in {\mathbb{C}}^{M \times M \times 2N-1}$ ?

Comment: It seemed too easy to be correct hehe. I interpreted E as the expected value,x(n)  the covariance of one sample. You meant the matrix R, where each element $R_{i,j} = E\{x(n-i)x^H(n-j)\}$ [for random vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Auto-correlation_of_random_vectors)?

By equalizing you mean to whiten the signal, to remove the correlation between different samples?

Comment: I was wrong. You were right. Take my upvote.

Comment: Thank you, now both of us are right :)